# Tool to pull components on object level

Tags: tools

is any tool to pull list of components(workflow, process builder, approval process, flows, triggers) on object level? Tedious activity to pull manually because we have close to 500+ custom objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing a retrieve on the Object should get Approvals, Workflow Rules, etc should get you most everything.

For example, using Salesforce DX:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Account
```

Would retrieve all fields, list views, page layouts, validation rules, workflow rules, etc related to Accounts.

For code and most other metadata types, use a MetadataComponentDependency Tooling API query:

```
SELECT MetadataComponentType, MetadataComponentName 
FROM MetadataComponentDependency 
WHERE RefMetadataComponentId = 'Account'
```

Where `'Account'` is an example to get all code related to the Account object. Use the 18-character ID to see all dependencies for custom objects or other custom features (e.g. classes), or the object name for standard objects.